# How do I simplify this addition interface?

Tags: c++

I've built this interface for things that are addable with themselves, and it's pretty nice so far. However, I have to do `*a+*b` to add things, and when you have to do `*(*a+*b)+*a`, using it gets pretty annoying pretty fast. Is there a way to modify it to be simpler to use?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>


class iResult
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<iResult> operator+(const iResult& rhs) const = 0 ;
    virtual std::string print() const = 0;
};


class intResult : public iResult
{
public:
    intResult(int b) : num(b) {};
    std::string print() const
    {
        return std::to_string(num);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<iResult> operator+(const iResult& rhs) const 
    {
        return std::make_shared<intResult>(num + dynamic_cast<const intResult&>(rhs).num);
    }
private:
    const int num;
};



int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<iResult> a = std::make_shared<intResult>(3);
    std::shared_ptr<iResult> b = std::make_shared<intResult>(4);
    std::shared_ptr<iResult> c = *a + *b;
    std::shared_ptr<iResult> z = *(*a + *b) + *a; //Gross!
    std::cout << c->print() << std::endl;
    std::cout << z->print() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the reason for using `std::shared_ptr`. Why would you return a different type for `operator +` that the type used for the operation?

Comment: Curious to hear what the use case is for this...

Comment: The actual class needs to stay behind an interface, it's managed by other stuff, so only a pointer to the interface should come back, which is living in a `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @Carbon, usage of overloaded operators probably makes more sense on [value types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3xI1HJUy7Q)

Comment: @WhiZTiM It seems crazy, there's a good reason for doing it, trust me.

Comment: what's the point of the interface if `intResult`s can only add `intResult`s?

Comment: But that's user responsibility. You shouldn't choose for the user whether to use `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, raw pointers or anything (just to mention Boost pointers, or auto_ptr).

Comment: Because in my use case, there are some types that can add other types.

Comment: Ah - should I give back a ref'd thing instead and just let them worry about the storage?

Comment: This will collapse if you try to add a `intResult` with another type of `iResult`. This is something your interface allows but your implementation doesn't support. It doesn't seem to me like polymorphism is appropriate here.

Comment: Not from `+`. That would be appropriate if you switch to `+=`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux there's an error type that's returned for incompatible return types.

Comment: You aren't catching the `std::bad_cast` from that reference `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @Carbon If derived types are only intercompatible with each other and not other types that derive from the same base, there doesn't seem to be any benefit to having a base type at all. Maybe templates are a better solution here.

Comment: Even if there is some overlap, it's much better to just provide (only the meaningful) free function `result_t operator+(const left_t &, const right_t &)`, and drop the base class. `intResult` only gets `intResult operator+(intResult, const intResult &)`, and the compiler tells you if you have gotten it wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add another layer of abstraction.  Since your `operator+` wants an `const iResult&` you can add another overload that takes `const std::shared_ptr<iResult>&` and does all the dereferencing in it.  If you add

```
std::shared_ptr<iResult> operator +(const std::shared_ptr<iResult>& rhs, const std::shared_ptr<iResult>& lhs)
{
    return *rhs + *lhs;
}
```

to the global space then in `main()`

```
std::shared_ptr<iResult> c = *a + *b;
std::shared_ptr<iResult> z = *(*a + *b) + *a; //Gross!
```

becomes

```
std::shared_ptr<iResult> c = a + b;
std::shared_ptr<iResult> z = a + b + a; //Nice!
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/086cb48f1119d6bd)